# Python ftplib does not see all files / directories

Tags: python, ftplib

I have been using a small script to download satellite data from the NOAA CLASS archive, using ftplib. Until recently this has been working flawlessly, but now I don't see the directory corresponding to my order. The ftplib query actually only sees a fraction of the directories available.

Below are a few lines that demonstrate that ftplib only sees a subset of the content in the root directory:

```
from ftplib import FTP
HOST = "ftp.class.ncdc.noaa.gov"
ftp = FTP(HOST)
ftp.login()
files = ftp.nlst()
print len(files)
is_ok = '2304318203' in files
print is_ok
ftp.quit()
```

It produces the following output:

```
1926
False
```

With a normal ftp session I see 7203 items under the root directory and in particular my directory with the ordered data:

```
Name (ftp.class.ngdc.noaa.gov:a000680): ftp
331 Any password will work
Password:
230 Any password will work
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd 2304318203
250 OK. Current directory is /2304318203
ftp> pwd
257 "/2304318203" is your current location
```

I am using Python 2.7, but as I said above, this has been working previously, with similar NOAA CLASS archive orders. So, could it be that the data provider has made some changes on their server which causes this strange behaviour?

Comment: I just tested the host using both `ftplib` and the CLI - I get the same directory listing from both. Am I right in thinking that you don't log in anonymously when you use the "normal ftp session"? That would explain seeing different listings...

Comment: Thanks. Well, I don't think so. I login anonymously in both cases. I use "ftp" and provide either nothing or my email-adress when using the CLI, and I have tried both ftp.login() and ftp.login('anonymous', <my-email-adress>) but no change. So, am I right you only see 1926 or so entries in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I log in to the normal command line client I don't see your job directory at all. When I ping the server I get an IP of `204.62.251.180`. If you get a different one then there may be some inconsistency in their servers. I would contact NOAA CLASS about this since it seems like it is a problem with their server and not the client connecting to them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have contacted NOAA CLASS now. Indeed I get a different IP: 140.172.19.180

Comment: Problem found! They have changed server since my last download, and the ip address differs by one letter, I didn't see that. Sorry for this. So, nothing wrong in ftplib or my usage of it! So, changing my script to use the host at ftp.class.ngdc.noaa.gov (which I used when doing the interactive FTP session in a shell) instead of ftp.class.ncdc.noaa.gov (which was where I used to download from) made the trick. Sorry again!